# Is it possible to temporarily disable the screen timeout?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, screen-timeout

Often, during updates/downloads or backup operations I would like to **temporarily disable the screen time** ( found under the '*menu - settings - Display - Screen timeout*' ) without having to navigate to the above menu setting .

Anybody knows of a good **widget** which does just that : either disable the screen time ( by just clicking the widget ) , or by setting it to a high value / back to short value ( also by just clicking the widget ).

Or is there any other easy way I have missed ?

I am running Froyo on Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: You can use a Developer setting to keep the screen always on when charging. `Menu | Settings | Manage applications | Development` Not ideal, perhaps, but maybe sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a profile application to set your volumes in different situations, I guest most of them have the option of changing your screen timeout as well. In my case I'm using [Setting Profiles](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.probeez.liteprofiles) and I can add a new profile that does exactly that in two key press.

In [Setting Profiles](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.probeez.liteprofiles), there is a widget to set profiles and you can even select a timer with the profiles you set, for instance, to enable the profile "no screen timeout" for the next 5 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Tasker is a great app for this.  It can change the screen timeout value to whatever you need depending on a phone state (there are several from phone orientation to a specific app being active).  For instance, I have it set to change the screen timeout value to 23 hours when it is in Navigation mode.  You can also define this task in Tasker and create a widget for it.

Comment: Do you have to set it back to the default again in Tasker?

Comment: Fast forward to now, Tasker has [Keep Screen On](https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8ne7oO4s%2BaDx%2FwlzjdFTfVMWstg1ay5AkpiNdrLoSXEZdFfw1IpXiyJCVLNW0yn&id=Project%3AKeep+Screen+On) project on Tasker Share, with description: "*Will make your second Tasker quick tile into a toggle that will set your screen time out alternately to 10 minutes and your normal timeout setting.*"

Answer (score 1):

LineageOS features a preinstalled FOSS app [Caffeine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=moe.zhs.caffeine&hl=en&gl=US) (that can also be installed to any other Android), that will present you a way to turn off the timeout for some time or indefinitely with a button on top of your notification shade.

Comment: Just a small clarification, "Caffeine" is a built-in feature of LineageOS, not a preinstalled app. This app is mimicking the feature instead.