# How to quickly change screen timeout

Tags: quick-settings, screen-timeout

My screen timeout is set to one minute, but there are cases when I temporarily want to change it to 30, which is the maximum value apparently.

The fastest way I found is to create a shortcut to the Display section of the settings app. I still need to close the app I'm in, click on the shortcut, then click timeout, then select 30 minutes.

Is there a faster way?

Ideally, I'd like to have an option to completely disable screen timeout in the quick settings dropdown, but I think it's up to the device manufacturer what's in that menu?

If it matters, I have a FairPhone 4 with Android 12

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [Is it possible to temporarily disable the screen timeout?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5957/44325), [How do I prevent Android from going to sleep?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/98539/44325)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Caffeine app which will provide a convenient tile in quick settings to indefinitely extend the screen time.

Available on Play Store and F-Droid: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/info.zwanenburg.caffeinetile/

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could try with the [Screen Timeout Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxlab.screentimeoutwidgetlite&hl=en&gl=US) app. It creates a small icon (widget to be correct) in your home screen and allows changing the screen timeout directly. It says that it can also be shown in the notifications panel, but strangely there are no screenshots with such feature.

From the author:

> Switches screen timeout from homescreen, notifications, quick
> settings. Lightweight and useful widget for switching timeout of the
> screen. For every added screen timeout widget you can select one or
> any of this sequentially switchable interval values:
>
> - 1 second
> - 5 seconds
> - 15 seconds
> - 30 seconds
> - 60 seconds
> - 2 minutes
> - 5 minutes
> - 10 minutes
> - 30 minutes
> - Never switched off

[image]